# Great-circle distance using haversine formula

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry, geodesy

I've been trying to calculate the distance between two locations following the haversine formula. I believe the formula is:

- $\Delta_\mathrm{lon}=\mathrm{lon}_1-\mathrm{lon}_2$
- $\Delta_\mathrm{lat}=\mathrm{lat}_1-\mathrm{lat}_2$
- $a=\sin^2\dfrac{\Delta\mathrm{lat}}{2}+\cos\mathrm{lat}_1\cos\mathrm{lat}_2\sin^2\dfrac{\Delta_\mathrm{lon}}{2}$
- $c=2\mathrm{atan2}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{1-a})$
- $d=Rc$

With $R$ the radius of the Earth and $d$ the distance between two points given by their longitude and latitude.

However, I'm stuck with $\sqrt{1-a}$.

Can anyone please help? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula. If you want to derive the formula, this will help too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I've tried those formula too and I'm getting a different answer @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: I used this https://www.easycalculation.com/trigonometry/atan2-calculator.php for calculating the atan2 since I'm unable to do it on a calculator, using https://www.desmos.com/scientific as my calculator btw. So it's either these tools are incorrect or I'm really doing something wrong.

Comment: @JonnahParis People are not down voting your post because of how stupid your question is. They are down voting for 2 reasons the first one being that you're not giving proper context to your question: what are $a, b, c$ ? Also you've written out all equations in regular bold font which makes it quite hard to read. Try using Mathjax to make things clearer. for example instead of writing **a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 ** write $$ a = \sin^2(\frac{\Delta L}{2}) $$ where $L$ is lat.

Comment: When you apply this function, you can avoid $c$ altogether Better to do it afresh                                                                                             
[Wiki][1]
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example: distance at mean sea level from [Santiago de Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago) to [Prague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prague). Coordinates from Wikipedia. Earth radius taken as 6,371 km.

- Santiago de Chile: 33°27'S 70°40'W
- Prague: 50°05'N 14°25'E

First, convert coordinates to decimal degrees, then radians. Take care of the signs (east longitude and north latitude are positive).

Degrees (lat/lon pairs):

- Santiago de Chile: -33.45, -70.67
- Prague: +50.08, +14.42

Radians (lat/lon pairs):

- Santiago de Chile: -0.5838, -1.2334
- Prague: +0.8741, +0.2516

Now simply apply the following formula, where $\varphi$ stands for latitude and $\lambda$ longitude.

$$d=2R\arcsin\sqrt{\sin^2\dfrac{\Delta\varphi}{2}+\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\sin^2\dfrac{\Delta\lambda}{2}}$$

Here $\Delta\varphi=1.4579$ and $\Delta\lambda=1.4850$.

The expression under the radical, that you call $a$ in your question, equals roughly $0.6884$. The distance $d\simeq12,469 \;\mathrm{km}$.

Seems close enough to the distance computed by [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=distance+from+prague+to+santiago).

Now try to redo this computation with your own tools. If you have a handheld calculator, it's more than enough.

---

Remark: while the formula with atan2(y,x) is useless, it's not wrong either. You can easily check that for $0<a<1$, $\mathrm{atan2}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{1-a})=\arcsin\sqrt{a}$. So you should find the same result with this formula.

---

While we are at it, here is how to derive the haversine formula, using the vector dot product. The points are given by their spherical coordinate $\varphi$ (latitude) and $\lambda$ (longitude). The cartesian coordinates are thus given by

- $x=R\cos\varphi\cos\lambda$
- $y=R\cos\varphi\sin\lambda$
- $z=R\sin\varphi$

The two vectors are $\overrightarrow{OM_1}$ and $\overrightarrow{OM_2}$, with $O$ being the sphere center.

$$\overrightarrow{OM_1}\cdot\overrightarrow{OM_2}=||\overrightarrow{OM_1}||\cdot||\overrightarrow{OM_2}||\cdot\cos(\overrightarrow{OM_1},\overrightarrow{OM_2})$$

In cartesian coordinates, the dot product can be written

$$R^2\cos(\overrightarrow{OM_1},\overrightarrow{OM_2})=R^2\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\cos\lambda_1\cos\lambda_2\\+R^2\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\sin\lambda_1\sin\lambda_2+R^2\sin\varphi_1\sin\varphi_2$$

The first two terms can be simplified using the formula $\cos(a-b)=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b$. The factor $R^2$ can also be removed as it appears on both sides. We will also denote the angle $(\overrightarrow{OM_1},\overrightarrow{OM_2})$ by $\theta$. Thus:

$$\cos\theta=\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\cos(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)+\sin\varphi_1\sin\varphi_2$$

It could be used as is, but when the distance is small (a common case), the cosine is very close to $1$, where it's flat. So taking the arccosine will not be very accurate. To transform the formula, use the relation $\cos a=1-2\sin^2\frac a2$.

$$1-2\sin^2\frac\theta2=\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\left(1-2\sin^2\dfrac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}\right)+\sin\varphi_1\sin\varphi_2$$

$$1-2\sin^2\frac\theta2=\cos(\varphi_1-\varphi_2)
-2\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\sin^2\dfrac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}$$

$$1-2\sin^2\frac\theta2=1-2\sin^2\frac{\varphi_1-\varphi_2}2
-2\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\sin^2\dfrac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}$$

And finally

$$\sin^2\frac\theta2=\sin^2\frac{\varphi_1-\varphi_2}2
+\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\sin^2\dfrac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}$$

Now, we can compute the angle $\theta$, and the distance is $d=R\theta$.

So

$$d=2R\arcsin\sqrt{\sin^2\frac{\varphi_1-\varphi_2}2
+\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\sin^2\dfrac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}}$$

*(it's ok to take the arcsine because the angle $\theta/2$ is necessarily in $[0,\pi/2]$)*

---

A last note about terminology. Why *haversine*? In the old days, special names were given to some trigonometric functions that are seldom used nowadays. The versine is defined by $\mathrm{versin}\,a=1-\cos a$. And the haversine is "half the versine", or

$$\mathrm{hav}\,a=\frac{1-\cos a}{2}=\sin^2\frac{a}{2}$$

The formula written above with squares of sines can be written more concisely with the haversine:

$$\mathrm{hav}\,\theta=\mathrm{hav}\,(\varphi_1-\varphi_2)
+\cos\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\mathrm{hav}\,(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)$$

Apart from conciseness, there is another advantage. In the old days, there were no electronic calculator and computations were made with [tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_table). Squaring the sine of half the angle means more calculations than necessary. Thus, for navigation and surveying purposes, there were also tables of versines or haversines, further simplifying the computations.