# Why is sine-squared used in the haversine formula?

Tags: numerical-methods, math-history, spherical-geometry, geodesy

The traditional "haversine" formula for great-circle distance is traditionally expressed as

$$
2R \arcsin\left(\sqrt{
  \sin\left(\frac{\Delta\varphi}{2}\right)^2 +
  \cos\left(\varphi_1\right)
  \cos\left(\varphi_2\right)
  \sin\left(\frac{\Delta\lambda}{2}\right)^2
}\right)
$$

See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2799410/117452).

Given the identity:

$$
\mathrm{haversin}\left( \theta \right) = \frac{1 - \cos\left( \theta \right)}{2} = \sin\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) ^2
$$

Why do we typically express the formula in terms of sine-squared, and not in terms of cosine? Does it look prettier? Is there an historical reason for doing it? Is it more numerically stable?

Comment: I can't tell, have you had a few weeks on vectors,  dot product and cross product?  Great circles on the sphere are a little nicer expressed in the Cartesian coordinates

Comment: $\sin^2(x/2)$ is obviously _always_ positive or zero but for the $\cos$ version this isn't obvious.

Comment: @WillJagy I had 4 years thereof, followed by several years of gradual skills atrophy which I've lately been attempting to reverse. I've recently had to start learning about GIS for work, which has taken me down the road of learning about spherical trigonometry.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou that makes sense, and I think it stands alone as an answer.

Comment: When the angle $\theta$ is small, then $\cos(\theta)$ is close to $1$ causing the difference $1-\cos(\theta)$ to lose significance while $\sin^2$ does not. The Wikipedia article [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) explains this.

Comment: @Somos I think that would also be a good answer, especially because floating-point stuff is tricky and my own understanding of it is shaky at best.

Comment: Thanks for that comment. I have posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closely related to this question is [MSE question 2874940](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2874940)
about cosine similarity. You can read my answer to
that question there. Briefly, when an angle $\theta$
is small, then $\cos(\theta)$ is close to $1$
causing the  difference $1−\cos(\theta)$ to lose significance ([Catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation)) while $\sin^2$ does not.
The Wikipedia article
[Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)
explains this particular case.

Comment: Just so I understand this, is this because the following point representation of a number very close to 0 has a very high precision compared to a number close to 1, resulting in possibly substantial precision loss in the subtraction?

Comment: @shadowtalker Exactly! Read the catastrophic cancellation link.

Answer (score 1):

My theory is that $\sin^2(x/2)$ is preferred because the result is *always* positive or zero, in contrast to answers containing $\cos(x)$ which does not make it so obvious.

Sometimes it is important to know when a quantity is non-negative, especially when used inside a radical.